# magento2 Rest api connect with c#

Tags: c#, rest, magento, magento2

I am trying to connect to magento2 Rest Api with C#, but i am getting following error when i am pushing login token again and want to get or post some data:

Consumer is not authorized to access %resources.
I am logging in as admin user.
Here's code i'm using to connect:

```
    public virtual void MagentoLogin()
    {

        restClient = new RestClient(MagentoServer + "/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json, charset=utf-8");
        request.Parameters.Clear();
        request.AddJsonBody(new { username = Login, password = Password });
        var response = restClient.Execute(request);
        string content = response.Content.ToString();
        content = content.Substring(2, content.Length - 3);
        LoginToken = content;

    }

    public virtual void Fetch()
    {
        string requeststring = MagentoServer + "/index.php/rest/V1/store/websites";
        restClient = new RestClient(requeststring);
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        Console.WriteLine("Login token>>>>>>>" + LoginToken + ">>>>>>>");
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("Authorization:Bearer ", LoginToken);
        request.Parameters.Clear();
        var response = restClient.Execute(request);
        string content = response.Content.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(content);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When i Was implementing basic oAuth i also got "acces denied" solution was setting Authorization header like this:

```
request.Headers.Set("Authorization",  
    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.access_token).ToString());
```

putting it "manually" like you did didn't made job. but i was using manual  `var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);` instead your RestClient. so you may need to change my solution to something like this:

```
request.AddHeader("Authorization ", 
    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", LoginToken).ToString());
```